# Euler polygon division algorithm

Tags: polygons

I am trying to enumerate and display all possible divisions of an `n`-polygon into `(n-2)` triangles (as in the following mathworld picture)

[image: Euler polygon division]

I know how to count how many divisions (Catalan numbers, `1, 2, 5, 14, 42, ...` ), but I am struggling to find a way to generate all the C(n-2) triangulations. Can anyone point to existing software implementation, or at least to an algorithm that generates these triangles?

Answer (score 1):

See: Hurtado and Noy, *[Graph of triangulations of a convex polygon and tree of triangulations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772199000164)*, Computational Geometry 13 (1999) pp179–188.

Section 3 of that paper gives a relatively straightforward method for constructing all triangulations of $n+1$-gons given all triangulations of $n$-gons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula to count the number of division to generate them.

Suppose you want to generate a division of a $n$-polygon whose vertices are $1, 2, …, n$. We know that there are $C_{n-2}$ such divisions (where $C_k$ is the $k$-th Catalan's number). What we need to do is:

- chose $2\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$ the other vertex of the triangle with edge $\{1, n\}$;
- chose a division of the polygon with vertices $1, 2, …, k$;
- chose a division of the polygon with vertices $k, k+1, …, n$.

Suppose you want to generate the $i$-th division of the $n$-polygon, $1\leqslant i\leqslant C_{n-2}$. Since we know that $C_{n-2} = \sum\limits_{j=2}^{n-1}C_{j-2}C_{n-1-j}$, we have a way to chose the value of $k$: chose the minimum $k$ such that $i\leqslant \sum\limits_{j=2}^kC_{j-2}C_{n-1-j}$.

We then need to chose the number $i_1$ of the division of the polygon $1, 2, …, k$ and the number $i_2$ of the division of the polygon $k, k+1, …, n$. Picking $i_1 = i\mod C_{k-2}$ and $i_2 = \left\lfloor \frac{i}{C_{k-2}}\right\rfloor$ will do the trick.

This gives the idea of a recursive algorithm to generate divisions. Note that the base case here is the polygon with $n=2$ (a simple edge).